# Mitigate memory leaks in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Even with low traffic to my app at GAE, the memory of the instances slowly build up and exceed the limit at 120 (something) megabyte.

At the moment I am seeing heavy traffic to the service, and accordingly the rate at which these memory errors appear have escalated. At the moment they happen every three minutes.

How do you mitigate these memory leaks? What are common errors that make memory build up like this?

> Exceeded soft private memory limit with 130.719 MB after servicing 548
>   requests total

Code example:

```
import BaseHandler
import webapp2

import time #for time stuff
import json #for output to app

class MainHandler(BaseHandler.BaseHandler):
    def respondjson(self, obj):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        rawjson = json.dumps(obj)
        self.response.write(rawjson)

    def get(self):
        thetime = int(time.time())
        #thetime += 86400 * 2
        #thetime += 60 * 20
        self.respondjson({'t':thetime})

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/gettime', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

This one API just returns time in a json response.

BaseHandler looks like this

```
import webapp2
import logging #for exception logging

class MissingparameterError(Exception):
     def __init__(self, value):
         self.value = value
     def __str__(self):
         return repr(self.value)

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def handle_exception(self, exception, debug_mode):
        # http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/exceptions.html

        if not isinstance(exception, MissingparameterError):
            # Log the error. We don't want to log errors of kind MissingparameterError.
            logging.exception(exception)
            #self.response.set_status(500)
            # Set a custom message.

        self.response.write('An error occurred.')
```

Comment: Maybe optimize your code? If you have a problem x, don't ask y.. Can you show some code that might be the culprit?

Comment: Code added. This is the simplest API example that has the instance memory go over the limit from time to time. It doesn't use any datastore or anything.

Comment: But from what you say this is not all of your code.  Each handler will be run by any instance, so the total memory will contributed by the entirety of your code.  Use apptrace https://code.google.com/p/apptrace/ on the dev server to profile your memory use.  I don't believe leaks are that common, I have instances that run for days, and max out under 70MB, and I never get memory errors, and my code is way more complex than anything you appear to be doing (ie running the full pyramid stack, deform, zpt for templating) implementing a CMS. And it's a relatively low volume site.

Comment: Currently one of the instances has had 622 requests, running for 4 hours, 18 min, 72.3MB  MBytes consumed.

Comment: I will definitely try apptrace. No, I don't believe the example above is the real culprit, still I can easily find many occasions in the error logs where the instances have gone down on this very call. Just guessing here but likely the memory built up in other API calls where I use ndb and memcache, and return some big media files in response to some requests. A "best memory practices" cheat-sheet hosted by Google would help, but I haven't found anything related to it (yet).

Comment: Best memory practices for appengine won't be any different to any other python based code that is expected to be long running.  I doubt the leak is ndb/memcache or it would affect everyone (the instance I mentioned earlier uses ndb/memcache heavily). The problem is most likely in your own code.  Thats where I would look first.